# jQuery Ajax function demo doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have downloaded the demo and have extracted the zip and uploaded the files to my server from this tutorial:

http://www.jquery4u.com/function-demos/ajax/

I downloaded that 10KB zip file and have attempted to run the sample index.html file both locally AND on my server but it doesn't seem to be working at all:

http://www.cinicraft.com/ajax-demo/ajax-demo.html

What could be causing the AJAX to suddenly not work properly?

thanks!

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?  What happens when you run it?  Do you see any errors?  Have you tried any of your own debugging?

Comment: I mean when you press load content 1 nothing happens when you download the sample code in the zip file. 
But when you try the "load content 1" button at http://www.jquery4u.com/function-demos/ajax/ it works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

You're using [the latest jQuery version](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js) in which [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) was removed. On line 122 you have `$('#overlay').live('click', function(e)...`

You can either downgrade the version of jQuery you're using, or update the code to use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/), the recommended replacement.

Answer (score 0):

I found a much better sample here:

http://tutorialzine.com/2009/09/simple-ajax-website-jquery/

It doesn't work locally but it works perfectly while on a server most likely since it uses PHP